# C# core implementation for a large threaded task handler

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing a web scraper in C#. I implemented it using `Thread` objects that take work from a pool of tasks and process all those elements against a callback and store the result. Pool of tasks means 5K - 50K input urls.

**Is there any core framework object that can deal with something like this?** I tried to see if the `Threadpool` can be instantiated but it can't. I'm also very unsure if such a hight number of tasks can/should be queued into the default `Threadpool`.

> So, is there anything already available in the core for creating a large number of tasks and a number of threads and have those threads process those tasks? Or should I just stick to my own. I've already reinvented a few wheels since I've been using C#.

Comment: Don't do it multithreaded. Do it single thread asynchronous. PS The point is that the Threadpool is a singleton.

Comment: @Aron What's the limit on async objects? I've thought about this but if each spawns a new thread... it's over. :) And if it's capped, what's the thread limit for asyncs?

Comment: @Aron In WinAPI there's a Threadpool similar to this that can have multiple instances.

Comment: I said "SINGLE THREAD ASYNC". Which means ONE THREAD.

Comment: @Aron So I start a lot of async objects on one thread and then I wait for them...? I come from C++. All this async stuff makes my head spin as I keep thinking... how many threads, how much memory, how fast, how efficient... I have no clue what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: If you come from C++ more the reason. You should understand asynchronous I/O then. You should understand OS events and you should understand callbacks and interrupts. If you don't understand, I suggest you read [Stephen Cleary's "There is no Thread"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: @Aron That post is interesting. The comments are better. Scraping and analyzing markup is CPU work and needs a thread.

Comment: Hardly any when your CPU isn't blocked on I/O :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

### Task Parallel Library (TPL)

> The Task Parallel Library (TPL) is a set of public types and APIs in the System.Threading and System.Threading.Tasks namespaces. The purpose of the TPL is to make developers more productive by simplifying the process of adding parallelism and concurrency to applications. The TPL scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most efficiently use all the processors that are available. In addition, the TPL handles the partitioning of the work, the scheduling of threads on the ThreadPool, cancellation support, state management, and other low-level details. By using TPL, you can maximize the performance of your code while focusing on the work that your program is designed to accomplish.

Tasks are queued onto the Thread pool by default using a TaskScheduler. The scheduler works to promote efficient use of available threads and processors.

You may also be interested in the Dataflow API that sits on top of it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

### Dataflow

> This dataflow model promotes actor-based programming by providing in-process message passing for coarse-grained dataflow and pipelining tasks. The dataflow components build on the types and scheduling infrastructure of the TPL and integrate with the C#, Visual Basic, and F# language support for asynchronous programming. These dataflow components are useful when you have multiple operations that must communicate with one another asynchronously or when you want to process data as it becomes available.

Comment: This would be `Parallel.ForEach`? If so, what's the thread count?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` will decide how many thread to spin up itself. You can however override the default behaviour with one of the overloads. However I would suggest you use asynchronous I/O for your web call, and `Task.Run` for your processing. Then use `await Task.WhenAll` to get all the results from all the scraped data.

Comment: @CodeAngry if you can trust the task scheduler to make best use of the available cores, does the thread count matter? Packet collisions in you network are likely to be a more restrictive bottleneck to throughput.

Comment: @CodeAngry I would also recommend Dataflow over `Parallel.ForEach`. Your project is a perfect candidate.

Comment: @Gusdor **Thank you!** Thought so too. I'm currently reading on it.